# Python subprocess.run timeout behaving differently on Windows vs Linux

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

The following snippet of code, running on `python 3.6.8` seem to behave very differently on Windows vs Linux

```py
from subprocess import run, PIPE
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from datetime import datetime as dt
import threading

def run_command(sleep, timeout):
    try:
        command = f"ping 127.0.0.1 -n {sleep + 1}"
        print(f"{dt.now()} - {threading.get_ident()} - {command}")
        out = run(command, timeout=timeout, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
        print(out)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{dt.now()} - {threading.get_ident()} - ", e)

if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as e:
        e.submit(run_command, 10, 1)
        e.submit(run_command, 10, 5)
```

I am expecting to get Linux behavior all the time, which is to print:

```
2021-03-04 15:15:40.276109 - 140510989964864 - ping 127.0.0.1 -n 11
2021-03-04 15:15:40.276998 - 140510981572160 - ping 127.0.0.1 -n 11
2021-03-04 15:15:41.279731 - 140510989964864 -  Command 'ping 127.0.0.1 -n 11' timed out after 1 seconds
2021-03-04 15:15:45.284004 - 140510981572160 -  Command 'ping 127.0.0.1 -n 11' timed out after 5 seconds
```

But when I run on Windows, it seems that both `subprocess.run` timeout "together", note the timings for the timeout. I don't know if the issue could be on the ThreadPoolExecutor as well

```
2021-03-04 15:14:49.671291 - 376104 - ping 127.0.0.1 -n 11
2021-03-04 15:14:49.671291 - 366200 - ping 127.0.0.1 -n 11
2021-03-04 15:15:00.179961 - 376104 -  Command 'ping 127.0.0.1 -n 11' timed out after 1 seconds
2021-03-04 15:15:00.179961 - 366200 -  Command 'ping 127.0.0.1 -n 11' timed out after 5 seconds
```

What do I have to do to get the same behavior when running this from Windows?

Comment: Try calling `run` with `shell=False`. You will have to split `command` with `command = command.spit()` so that you are now passing to `run` a list.

Comment: This does not make any difference

Comment: It did for me on my Windows desktop.

Comment: You are probably not using python 3.6, unfortunately I'm stuck with 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `run` with `shell=False`. You will have to split command with `command = command.spit()` so that you are now passing to `run` a list:

```py
from subprocess import run, PIPE
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from datetime import datetime as dt
import threading

def run_command(sleep, timeout):
    try:
        command = f"ping 127.0.0.1 -n {sleep + 1}"
        command = command.split()
        print(f"{dt.now()} - {threading.get_ident()} - {command}")
        out = run(command, timeout=timeout, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=False)
        print(out)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{dt.now()} - {threading.get_ident()} - ", e)

if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as e:
        e.submit(run_command, 10, 1)
        e.submit(run_command, 10, 5)
```

Prints:

```
2021-03-06 16:45:04.011326 - 8516 - ['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']
2021-03-06 16:45:04.012325 - 28136 - ['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']
2021-03-06 16:45:05.022674 - 8516 -  Command '['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']' timed out after 1 seconds
2021-03-06 16:45:09.023190 - 28136 -  Command '['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']' timed out after 5 seconds
```

**Update**

I switched to Python 3.6.4 and saw the OP's problem. Just for the heck of it I switched to using an equivalent implementation using `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`:

```py
from subprocess import run, PIPE
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from datetime import datetime as dt
import threading

def run_command(sleep, timeout):
    try:
        command = f"ping 127.0.0.1 -n {sleep + 1}"
        command = command.split()
        print(f"{dt.now()} - {threading.get_ident()} - {command}")
        out = run(command, timeout=timeout, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=False)
        print(out)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{dt.now()} - {threading.get_ident()} - ", e)

if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    p = ThreadPool(2)
    p.apply_async(run_command, (10, 1))
    p.apply_async(run_command, (10, 5))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

I then ran this several times and one time (the third occurrence) the results were correct (see below). So I went back to the original version with `ThreadPoolExecutor` and ran it about 10 times under Python 3.6.4 but did not succeed in producing a correct answer.

```
C:\Program Files\Python36>python -V
Python 3.6.4

C:\Program Files\Python36>python \booboo\test\test.py
2021-03-06 16:53:52.051412 - 21732 - ['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']
2021-03-06 16:53:52.052379 - 11744 - ['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']
2021-03-06 16:53:57.058553 - 21732 -  Command '['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']' timed out after 1 seconds
2021-03-06 16:53:57.060555 - 11744 -  Command '['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']' timed out after 5 seconds

C:\Program Files\Python36>python \booboo\test\test.py
2021-03-06 16:58:58.173625 - 17672 - ['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']
2021-03-06 16:58:58.173625 - 22920 - ['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']
2021-03-06 16:59:03.181457 - 17672 -  Command '['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']' timed out after 1 seconds
2021-03-06 16:59:03.186461 - 22920 -  Command '['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']' timed out after 5 seconds

C:\Program Files\Python36>python \booboo\test\test.py
2021-03-06 16:59:19.643543 - 22272 - ['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']
2021-03-06 16:59:19.643543 - 30580 - ['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']
2021-03-06 16:59:20.654799 - 22272 -  Command '['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']' timed out after 1 seconds
2021-03-06 16:59:24.651398 - 30580 -  Command '['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']' timed out after 5 seconds

C:\Program Files\Python36>python \booboo\test\test.py
2021-03-06 16:59:46.907140 - 27496 - ['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']
2021-03-06 16:59:46.907140 - 30460 - ['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']
2021-03-06 16:59:51.915997 - 27496 -  Command '['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']' timed out after 1 seconds
2021-03-06 16:59:51.922999 - 30460 -  Command '['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']' timed out after 5 seconds

C:\Program Files\Python36>
```

**Update 2**

Using multiprocessing, it works:

```py
from subprocess import run, PIPE
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from datetime import datetime as dt
import threading

def run_command(sleep, timeout):
    try:
        command = f"ping 127.0.0.1 -n {sleep + 1}"
        command = command.split()
        print(f"{dt.now()} - {threading.get_ident()} - {command}")
        out = run(command, timeout=timeout, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=False)
        print(out)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{dt.now()} - {threading.get_ident()} - ", e)

if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as e:
        e.submit(run_command, 10, 1)
        e.submit(run_command, 10, 5)
```

```
C:\Program Files\Python36>python \booboo\test\test.py
2021-03-06 17:11:32.402874 - 7724 - ['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']
2021-03-06 17:11:32.403878 - 26884 - ['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']
2021-03-06 17:11:33.416621 - 7724 -  Command '['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']' timed out after 1 seconds
2021-03-06 17:11:37.414169 - 26884 -  Command '['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']' timed out after 5 seconds
```

Comment: Are you using python 3.6? This gives me the exact same result


`2021-03-06 18:50:29.797394 - 72804 - ['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']`
`2021-03-06 18:50:29.797394 - 70072 - ['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']`
`2021-03-06 18:50:34.816661 - 72804 -  Command '['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']' timed out after 1 seconds`
`2021-03-06 18:50:34.817663 - 70072 -  Command '['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-n', '11']' timed out after 5 second`

Comment: See updated answer. Interesting but not great.

Comment: And finally with multiprocessing it works.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the issue is that python 3.7+ has `close_fds=True` by default, and we can't use that with python 3.6 (not if you also want to capture the output)

Commenting the `subprocess.py` code that checks if `close_fds` is set on Windows makes this behave correctly, this is interesting but does not solve my issue, might have to use a reimplementation of `Popen`

 I can't use multiprocessing as well, I'm running embedded python in a C++ binary, no guarantees of a python intepreter present on the machine.

Comment: From: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html 

`Changed in version 3.7: On Windows the default for close_fds was changed from False to True when redirecting the standard handles. It’s now possible to set close_fds to True when redirecting the standard handles.`

Unfortunately it looks like this was fixed in the c side, so I can't easily get this working on python 3.6

Comment: This is the issue with the fix for 3.7+: https://bugs.python.org/issue19764